# Change Codeigniter url

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter.I want to set href attr to something like :

```
<a href="/contact.html" >Contact</a>
```

But i get 404 error because i should write

```
<a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>.
```

Where is some thing to fix this problem.

Any help please.

Comment: Uh, so you _do_ know how to fix your problem, but you are looking for a solution that will let you keep the incorrect URL in place why exactly?

Comment: I have never seen someone using CI and want to set .html page instead of view location?

Comment: .html ? in CodeIgniter ? Are you sure ?

Comment: So i'm using js file which is not accept php script to send ajax request, then i think i should specify the url

Comment: @mallix , i'm using $config['url_suffix'] = '.html';

Comment: So is `contact`, the name of your controller? and do you have a method called `index` in that controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a controller by the name **Contact** and you successfully extend the **CI_Controller** class, go to **application/config** folder and in **config.php** find:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.youdomain.com/';
```

Then in your internal links you should do:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a>
```

If you are using **javascript** to make the redirect, put on top of the **js** file:

```
var host = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/';
```

Again:

```
window.location.href = host + 'contact';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using codeigniter, you do not want to point to an .html file.

If you're using codeigniter correctly, you should use the helper methods that exist in codeigniter.

Instead of writing the anchor tag yourself, try this:

```
<?php echo anchor('contact', 'Contact'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to add the suffix to your controller in calling go to **config/config.php** and search for

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

and assign html to it to become

```
$config['url_suffix'] = 'html';
```